# How to prove if the statement "If A is a nonsingular matrix, then the homogeneous system Ax = 0 has a nontrivial solution" is true or false?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, solution-verification, matrix-equations

Statement: `If  is a nonsingular matrix, then the homogeneous system  = 0 has a nontrivial solution`

We know that if A is an n × n non–singular
matrix, then the homogeneous system
AX = 0 has only the trivial solution X = 0.
Hence if the system AX = 0 has a non–trivial
solution, A is singular.

Example:

[image: matrix A]

By solving the row echelon form of A, we get:

[image: row echelon form]

Because of this, we can say that A is singular because we got its reduced row echelon form,
and consequently AX = 0 has a non–trivial
solution x = −1, y = −1, z = 1

More generally, if A is
row–equivalent to a matrix containing a zero
row, then A is singular. For then the
homogeneous system AX = 0 has a
non–trivial solution.

Now, my issue here is that I hesitate to conclude if the given statement above is considered true or false because of the presence of the possibility in the matrix that it can be either trivial or non-trivial. I may want to know what is the final verdict for the statement above if it's true or false.

Your responses would be highly appreciated as this would help me a lot to get a clearer context.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $A$ is nonsingular, it has an inverse $A^{-1}.$ (If you have not seen this fact or do not want to use it, I'll remove this answer.) Therefore if $x$ is any solution to $Ax=0$, then $$x = (A^{-1}A)x = A^{-1}(Ax) = A^{-1}0 =0,$$
so that $Ax=0$ indeed only has the trivial solution.

Comment: I see, thus despite the possibility of the statement having a nontrivial solution, your explanation here would prove that if  is a nonsingular matrix, then the homogeneous system  = 0 can only have a trivial solution, which makes the given statement above false? @Steven

Comment: @RalphHenry yes indeed

Comment: ok got it, that would do, thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 2):

If $A$ is a square invertible matrix, being full rank and being invertible is equivalent.

Therefore we can use the rank–nullity theorem and see that the kernel of your matrix is a vector space whose dimension is necessarily $0$, meaning that it only contains the null vector.

So there is only the trivial solution.

Comment: Oh ok, now if that is the case where it can have infinitely many non-trivial solutions, then we can say that the statement above is true?(since it assumes Ax=0 has a nontrivial solution) @Lelouch

Comment: @RalphHenry Mh sorry I read your post too fast, I thought you were assuming a singular matrix, not a nonsingular matrix. If the matrix is invertible there is only the trivial solution. Your statement is false.

Comment: no worries, thanks for the correction also. I see I see, ok will take note of that one. Thank you very much!!!

Answer (score 0):

The given statement is FALSE. Since $A$ is non-singular means $det(A)\ne 0$ hence the homogeneous system $Ax=0$ can be solved as :
$A^{-1}(Ax)=A^{-1}0$
$\implies (A^{-1}A)x=0$
$\implies Ix=0$
$\implies x=0$
i.e. Trivial solution